# project missing fake folder myEclipse

Tags: jakarta-ee, myeclipse

i'm working under myEclipse and in a Java EE environnement , i recently added a js file to the webroot , then , myeclipse is indicating this error which prevents the project from being built

```
Project 'GRH' is missing required source folder: 'KickStart'
```

Kickstart is the name of the js file , i don't konw why i'm getting this error , i removed the js file , the problem is still remaining , i redeployed the project , changes on src folder are not considered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following : (May be helpful)

Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path  -> unselect the src, save it & select again.

The reason to unselect src is because this src folder contains com/yourpackage/ so when you unselect it, it will take the new one and rebuilt as well